# How to maximize number of inserts in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, insert, max, limit

I am working on a script for uploading images to a DB and a rootmap. The script is working perfectly except for one thing. I like to restrict the number of uploads to a maximum of 3 when a certain category (thema) is chosen to categorize the image. The script I use does the trick but is does too much. It restricts the upload of images not only for the requested category but for all other categories as well as soon as the set maximum of 3 is reached. As far as I know it is the logical result of the script but I need to add some code that will allow image uploads in other categories that are not restricted by a maximum. Is anyone able to help me out?

The code I use is here: the category that is maximized is named 'special'. The category (i.e. $theme), $photographer etc are set through a session variable.

```php
// Check for maximum upload
$maximum = $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM wp_daguerre_media WHERE thema = 'special' AND fotograaf ='$fotograaf'")
    ->fetchColumn();

if ($maximum >= 3) { 
    $msg = "<style='color:red;'>Je hebt al 3 fotos voor de 'special' geupload.<br>Drie is het maximum. 
        Kies een ander thema.</style><br>"; 
} else {
    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: So add it to your if condition then …? `if ($categoryHoldingVariable == 'special' && $maximum>=3)` …?

Comment: (Might make sense to structure this a little differently though, because if the category is not `special`, then the database query above would need to be performed in the first place.)

Comment: ...and you should be using a prepared statement.

Comment: @CBroe that's the solution! Thnx!